# Displaying custom error when sending Laravel email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.6, laravel-mail

The code below works perfectly when the provided email in the second send function is correct $cm1['email'], however, when the user enters a not working email Laravel error page is displayed and the condition I wrote that redirect('/cm') with the error message doesn't work. So my question is how to make Laravel redirect the user to the page with error flash message when something wrong happens while sending the email instead of displaying the error.

```
     Mail::send('email_contact', ['data' => $cm1], function ($message)
    {

        $message->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'No Reply');
        $message->to('rec@gmail.com');

    });

    Mail::send('email_rec', ['data' => $cm1],function ($message) use ($cm1) {

        $message->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'No Reply');
        $message->to( $cm1['email']);

    });
    if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {
        return redirect('/cm')->with('flash_message','<strong> Something went wrong! </strong> The entered email seems to be invalid Received');
    }

    return redirect('/cm')->with('flash_message','<strong> Thank You! </strong> Your Inquiry Has Been Received');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in app/Exceptions/Handler.php file like below.
May be this will solve your problem.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {

            // not authorized
            case '403':
                return \Response::view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode(), [],403);
                break;

            // not found
            case '404':
                return \Response::view('errors.403', [],404);
                break;

            // not found
            case '405':
                return \Response::view('errors.403', [],405);
                break;

            // internal error
            case '500':
                return \Response::view('errors.403',[],500);
                break;

            default:
                return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
        }
    }elseif ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => "Something want wrong.!!"]);
    }elseif ($e instanceof QueryException){
        return back();
    }elseif ($e instanceof PDOException){
        return back();
    }
    else {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

In view you can set your view file to render

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but actually what is happening is that I'm getting the data from the form and using them for 1) send an email to my self, 2) send an email to the user. but the issue is occurring when the user is putting an invalid email so laravel get stuck and display error. Instead of displaying the error page I want to transfer the user back to the form and display flash message to check his email again. and I don't want to change the whole 500 error message return.